# LaunchedEffect starts more that once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, side-effects

I met the problem, which consists in that `LaunchedEffect` works incorrectly. I want to `block` in `LaunchedEffect` start once, when user click to corresponding `NavigationBarItem`, because `block` should send only one request to the server. I added immutable parameter `Unit` to `block` be non restartable, but tool **AppInspection** displays that network is using everytime when I click on the navigation button

```
@Composable
fun PostScreen(postsViewModel: PostsViewModel) {

    val state = postsViewModel.posts.observeAsState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        state.value?.forEach {
            item { Post(it) }
        } ?: item { CircularProgressIndicator() }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        postsViewModel.getAllPosts()
    })
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`LaunchedEffect(Unit)` executes a block once when the Composable enters the screen. It fires again whenever you navigate away and then reselect the BottomNavigation item.

Assuming you have the NavHost and BottomNavigation set up with `saveState=true` and `restoreState=true` according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav), a solution could be as simple as:

```
@Composable
fun PostScreen(postsViewModel: PostsViewModel) {

    var initialComposition by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(true) }
    val state = postsViewModel.posts.observeAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (initialComposition) {
            postsViewModel.getAllPosts()
            initialComposition = false
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This probably might be the issue. LaunachedEffect is remember under the hood. On recomposition neither `LaunchedEffect` nor remember should restart